# Multiple Sizes and respective quantity

Tags: attributes, quantity

I have products with different sizes and their availability varies.
Like Product A is available in S, M, L, XL and the respective availability is 0,2,5,1

How to configure it in Magento.

Answer (score 1):

The inventory is managed through each associated simple product.

- Simple Product A - Size S: Qty 2
- Simple Product B - Size M: Qty 5
- Simple Product C - Size L: Qty 1

The stock (quantity) for the configurable product where all these simple products are associated is 0.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a configurable product,where the associated products will be four simple products with various size and stock.

So when user will select size the stock quantity will be automatically adjusted.

for details about how to create a configurable product you can check [this link](http://www.templatemonster.com/help/how-create-configurable-product.html).